# ssh - Could not open a connection to your authentication agent

Tags: ssh

Have tried everything I found in Google. Nothing seems to work.
Here is what I've done.

```
user@home-machine ~ $ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa): 
/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? y
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx user@home-machine
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 4096]----+
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
+-----------------+

user@home-machine ~ $ ssh-copy-id user@vps
user@vps's password: 
Now try logging into the machine, with "ssh 'user@vps'", and check in:

  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

to make sure we haven't added extra keys that you weren't expecting.



user@home-machine ~ $ ssh user@vps 
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
user@vps's password: 

user@vps:~$ ssh-add
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
user@vps:~$ eval "$(ssh-agent)"
Agent pid 1501
```

I logged out, tried again and I still get the message:

> Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.

I try again ssh-add and I get:

> Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

I deleted .ssh/authorized_keys and tried all over again and still nothing.

Comment: `ssh -vv user@vps` or `ssh -vvv user@vps` will provide more (and much more) explanatory output.  Posting that will make a diagnosis much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to find the processes running an `ssh-agent` and terminate them, the agent might be behaving incorrectly.

Also, note that the `ssh-agent` having trouble has nothing to do with your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

The `ssh-agent` is a helper to aid with `ssh` logins, by caching your passphrase in memory, so you don't have to type it every time you use it.

I have get used to add a call to the `keychain` utility to my `~/.bash_profile` to help managing my `ssh-agent` (and my `gpg-agent`, but that's another story).

Simply put this line in your `~/.bash_profile` (or `~/.bashrc`, depending on your references, there are subtle differences):

```
eval $(keychain --clear --eval id_rsa id_dsa id_ecdsa other.id_rsa)
```

This way, you'll be prompted to type the passphrase of your keys **only once** in your entire shell session.

`keychain` is packaged in Debian and derivatives, but it is just a shell script. If your distribution does not have it, you can find it [here](http://www.github.com/funtoo/keychain). Just put it somewhere in your PATH. It is advisable to `chown` it `root:root` and `chmod` it `rwxr-xr-x` (755) to avoid unprivileged users modifying it.

Don't use keys without passphrase.